# Windows to Mac transformation

Tags: .net, macos

I just have development experience in .Net and Windows... 
And now I really want have some hands on experience of development on Mac.
So guys, how do I proceed (Well I'll get Mac first), suggestions please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to learn Objective-C first. It's C-based language, with object oriented capabilities mostly inherited from smalltalk.

I found [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213149) book amazing. (I think the third edition is coming)

And of course, you'll have to get used to XCode and Apple provided development tools (gdb, instruments). I think you will miss Visual Studio (which in my opinion is more solid than XCode) but you'll get rewarded with Cocoa experience. You can make you application really look very neat with no much work.

The bright side of this is that you will be able to develop for iPhone as well. Although is not the exact same framework (Cocoa vs. Cocoa Touch) they share basic concepts and programming language.

Comment: Thanks Pablo, are these tools for free or I need to pay for it

Comment: The 3rd edition of Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X has been out for a while now.

Comment: XCode and the iPhone SDK are free, but you need Mac OS X for both and an Intel Mac for the latter.

Comment: There is a third edition out as well http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-OS-3rd/dp/0321503619/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1240554066&sr=1-1